# Decide if a Clip is Included Inside a Bigger Video File

Tags: opencv, search, computer-vision, video-processing

I have a few short video clips and have to decide whether the clips are played in a long video file.

It is actually a bunch of ~1min video ads baked in a 24 hour long TV stream. I want to find out when those ads happen, the ad videos are givens before hand.

Comment: Any requirements about the quality and perfectness of the videos? Noise, color distortion, encodimg artifacts, dropped frames, etc. havebto be handled? Some methods which are or are not approppriate to compare single frames are image hashing, keypoint matching, template matching and others. To handle the video comparison I would get inspiration from (sub)string matching, once you solved the single frame matching.

Comment: @FazeL You don't have a code-related question though. Have you tried anything and what part is not working as expected? If you need a start... Take an early frame from the advert then try to find same pixels in the main video (check frame by frame). Both pictures must have matching widths/heights. You find by comparing pixel values using `==`. If all pixels in main video frame match same colours as the adverts' frame then you are looking at same thing. From there you can skip forward in main video by x-amount to confirm adverts ending is there too

Comment: @Micka It is  up to me to put much of the constraints, the use case is generating a table of aired commercials given the set of commercials in a TV channel, The aspect ratio is the same, reencoding should be covered, some minor processing could happen but we could just grab one of the processed ones from the air once and use that as the input.

Comment: @VC.One You are right I am looking for name of the problem since it smells like it could have a out of the shelf solution which I don't know. Or there could be simple solutions. My idea till now is to use phashes of the first few frame of ads and mach everything from then on. But I think It could be done with SSIM or similar measures too.

Comment: @FazeL What you need is template (or block) matching. But in your case, since the videos are embedded (baked) into the larger video, it should be enough to look for matching pixel values. That means checking if a frame from main video has same first pixel as your advert frame's first pixel colour, if yes, the check rest of pixels in frame or else if not matching then skip to next frame (at any occurrence of not matching)...

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for the ideas, I want more of relative robustness to transforms like luminescence or such changes, e.g. matching pixels on a convolution of the first image could be great.